# Having trouble getting my external JS file to work

Tags: javascript, html, external

I'm having some issues getting an external JS file to work.  It tends to work fine if I put it directly in my HTML, but not if I try to link it to an external file.  I'm trying to use JS to get smooth scrolling for my one-page website.

Below is where I have my external JS file linked at the bottom of my HTML and the beginning of the JS that I'm writing.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var scollLink = $('.scroll');

  // Smooth scrolling
  scrollLink.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  })

})
```

```html
<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make sure that your html file is in the root and the folder "js" is also in the root of your project so there's no problem. If your html file isn't at the root put your source like this: `src="./js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help so far, I've managed to figure it out.  I had misspelled "scroll" as "scoll" in my JS XD.

Everything's working fine now, thanks again!